# matplotlib - plt.coutourf - extend contours to boundary points

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am using the following code to make the plot shown on the link below:

```
plt.subplot(426)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15,20]
plt.contourf(X,Y,z6,[1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2],cmap='rainbow')
plt.title('Grid Spacing [m]'); plt.xlabel('x axis'); plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.plot(coord_x,coord_y,'rx'); plt.colorbar(extend='both', ticks=[1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]) 
plt.plot(point_x,point_y,'k.')
```

[countour plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io6SK.jpg)

Is there any way that I can extend the contours to the boundary points on the right side of the image?
The value in all those points corresponds to the lower limit (1.0).

Thanks in advance for any help!
Regards.

Comment: Since `X` ,`Y` and `coord_x`, `coord_y` are not given in the question, one cannot answer this. See [mcve].

Comment: Appologies for the incomplete information.